# Understanding ipmitool output for "Power Supply" (PSU)

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, ipmi, power-supply-unit

This Ubuntu server has two PSUs, I just ran ipmitool and it reported as follows:

```
# ipmitool sdr type "Power Supply"
PMBPower1        | DFh | ok  | 10.0 | 624 Watts
PMBPower2        | E4h | lnr | 10.0 | 0 Watts
PSU1 AC Lost     | E1h | ok  | 10.0 | Presence detected
PSU1 PWR Detect  | E3h | ok  | 10.0 | Presence detected
PSU2 AC Lost     | E6h | ok  | 10.0 | Presence detected
PSU2 PWR Detect  | E8h | ok  | 10.0 | Presence detected
```

I just need a bit of help understanding that output.

I guess PSU1 is ok and drawing 624Watts, but what is PSU2 doing? what is "lnr" is it just in standby or do I need to visit the DC?

What does AC Lost E6H mean? and PWR Detect E8h mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the man page, `lnr` means "Lower non-recoverable" which suggests strongly that it's time to get a replacement for PSU2.

The `AC Lost` and `PWR Detect` entries would almost certainly be showing that those sensors are present and report themselves as healthy.

Comment: Just went to the DC, all lights are green.

Comment: If you're really brave, reboot that server, then when it's at the BIOS screen during the boot process, pull power to PSU1 and see if PSU2 picks up. It's possible that IPMI is incorrectly reading standby as failed, but without actually testing it's hard to know.

Comment: thx... yea, there is no way i can do that with this server, lol... i will order a replacement part and wait.